# Monitor a file inside GCS Storage bucket using Prometheus

Tags: google-cloud-storage, prometheus, grafana, google-cloud-stackdriver

hi I am learning Prometheus and Grafana and here is my use case summary

1. I have created a sample GCS bucket inside my project and I uploaded a sample file inside that bucket.
2. I have installed Grafana, Prometheus and Stack driver; Configured storage api for Prometheus with Stack driver compute and storage apis
3. The Grafana, Prometheus are running successfully

Now I need to monitor the sample file in my storage bucket at every 5m interval using Prometheus query and populate the availability metrics in Grafana Dashboard. Any one could help me how to do it?

Comment: If the file in Cloud Storage (GCS) is a text file in Prometheus' Exposition format, and you've made it publicly accessible (an easy way to do this would be to use the bucket to host a static web site) you should be able to reference the file's URL directly as the scrape config target in your `prometheus.yml`. However, such targets need to be updated periodically in order to be useful in representing changing metrics. Do you have something updating the GCS file?

Comment: You should not need to use Stackdriver or enable the compute and storage APIs. Prometheus just needs a suitably-formatted text file at the end of an HTTP endpoint and you can do all that with just GCS (although still with my caveat of how is the file changing?)

Comment: You can periodically test if your file is still here, for instance with  cloud scheduler and observe these logs with Prometheus. Or consider that the file is here until something change, update, delete it, and this time activate the audit logs on Cloud Storage and get these logs in Prometheus to track file changes.